# In a topos, is the category of internal $R$-modules abelian for $R$ commutative and unitary?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, topos-theory

Let $\mathcal E$ be a topos and $R$ be a commutative unitary ring object in it. Let $R$-$\mathsf{Mod}$ be the category of (internal) $R$-modules. Is this category abelian? Does it at least have biproducts? Is it maybe even Grothendieck abelian?

I ask because using the internal language we have an easy morphism $R^m\to R^{m+n}\cong R^m\times R^n$ which seem like a coproduct injection, but I'm not sure how to prove the universal property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was hiding in Johnstone's *Topos Theory*, chapter 8, theorem 8.11. The statement there is for the category of internal abelian groups, but the same argument seems to work for $R$-modules.

**Theorem.**

- For any topos $\mathcal E$, with commutative unitary ring object $R$, the category $R$-$\mathsf{Mod}$ of internal $R$-modules is abelian;
- If $\mathcal E$ has a natural number object, $R$-$\mathsf{Mod}$ is monadic over $\mathcal E$;
- If $\mathcal E$ is a Grothendieck topos, $R$-$\mathsf{Mod}$ is a Grothendieck abelian category with a generator.

Comment: You can verify that the category of internal $R$-modules is by practically repeating the usual proof (which is constructive) in the, you guessed it, internal language. There is one thing to watch out. For instance, it doesn't suffice to internally show that given a morphism $\varphi:A \to B$ *there exists* a module $K$ and a linear map $K \to A$ such that $K \to A$ is a kernel of $\varphi$. Instead one has to explicitly write down a suitable $K$ and a suitable map $K \to A$. Else you only show *local existence* of kernels.